# Jest + Enzyme test: how to ensure a certain function is passed as prop to a component

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I am testing a React component that has several nested components within. My tests aim to make sure each component is given the right props. One of those components should be passed an onChange **function**, so I tried to do the following (inside `test()`):

**Jest + Enzyme Test:**

```
const props = {
  onSomethingChange: jest.fn()
};

const component = shallow(<MyComponent {...props} />);

expect(component.find('SomeNestedComponent')
  .prop('onSomethingChange')).toBe(props.onSomethingChange);
```

The test fails with the following (note: I also tried `.toEqual`):

```
Expected value to equal:
  [Function mockConstructor]
Received:
  [Function anonymous]
```

The definition for my component follows:

**MyComponent**

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  onSomethingChange = (event) => {
    // do something
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <SomeNestedComponent onSomethingChange={this.onSomethingChange} />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I make sure the correct function is passed as prop (and not just any other function)? Note that I don't call the function anytime; I just define it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out what is wrong with the construct in the question. The problem is the `onSomethingChange` function is a **component instance method** and not a prop of the `MyComponent` component itself. So the `onSomethingChange` prop in `SomeNestedComponent` was referring to the `onSomethingChange` method in `MyComponent` (thus not being equal to its prop set up in the test). The fix is to simply compare `SomeNestedComponent`'s prop to `MyComponent`'s **instance method** as follows:

```
expect(component.find('SomeNestedComponent')
  .prop('onSomethingChange')).toBe(component.instance().onSomethingChange);
```

The **instance()** function will allow you to get all the functions available within the component.

Comment: A maybe a bit more direct approach would be to just call the function using `.simulate` and test it with `expect(props. onSomethingChange).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Comment: I wonder how you do something similar with Functional Components

Comment: @tony did you ever find an answer? I'm REALLY desperate....